# Advanced Custom Fields changes get stuck in cache

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, cache

I'm using the Repeater Field in Advanced Custom Fields to handle a carousel slider changes slides by activation and expiration dates.

I'm not using any caching plugins, but I am hosted with WP Engine (caching server side is definitely happening). I had WP Engine turn the caching off and everything worked perfect, but they wouldn't leave it off and they didn't provide any workable solution.

If I manually hit 'Update' on the page in WordPress then the changes will show on the page too, but that solution doesn't work as the slide changes need to be automated (they change out several times a day and very precise times).

My question is if there's a better way to write my condition so that once the dates from the Datepicker field meet the requirements that the DOM will populate in a way where caching doesn't prevent it from showing.

```
if (have_rows('single_slide')) {
   $i = 1;
   while (have_rows('single_slide') && $i <= 5) {
      the_row();
      $currentTime = current_time( 'mysql' );
      $activationDate = get_sub_field('activation_date');
      $expirationDate = get_sub_field('expiration_date');

      if (($activationDate == '' || $activationDate < $currentTime) && ($expirationDate == '' || $expirationDate > $currentTime )) {
         $slider_title = get_sub_field('slide_title');
         $slider_text = get_sub_field('slide_subtitle');
         $slider_image = get_sub_field('slide_image')['url'];
         $slider_button_text = get_sub_field('button_text');
         $ slider_link = get_sub_field('button_url');

         if (!empty( $header_title ) || !empty( $slider_text ) || !empty( $slider_image ) ) {
                        <display the slide>
         }
         $i++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://aaronjholbrook.com/programmatically-clear-wp-engine-cache/

Comment: @WebElaine Thank you for the lead. I just tried it out on the site and tried the different methods that were mentioned on the GitHub page, but no luck. WP Engine seems to have been going through a lot of changes lately too, so what might have worked before may no longer.

Comment: It would be kind of hacky, but you could set up a cron job that updates the post(s) in question - reads what's already there, writes the same thing, and the cron "updates" it which triggers the WPE cache update. At least since they have revisions off by default your db shouldn't bloat from that standpoint.

Comment: That's a good idea. Maybe just the act of running a cron will stop that section/page from getting cached. I was digging around the Post Expirator plugin, as that runs updates on a schedule that don't get caught in the cache - all I could find of significance was the action of running a cron. I'll give that shot right now.

Comment: I was able to get in touch with one of WP Engine's chief technicians and their servers are configured to even stop most cron jobs from escaping the cache. They said that what I'm trying to do is intentional on their servers and isn't allowed basically - the cache refreshes approximately every 10-15 minutes. To force a cache on the page I have to physically click the Update button on that page/post.